# Racket - Two Lists Problem with comparing a list and a value

Tags: racket

I'm trying to write a function which consumes a list of destinations, a list of prices corresponding to the destinations, and a budget. It then produces a list of strings representing the destinations along with their prices, separated by a space, that are affordable according to the budget.
Can someone help me find the mistakes within my code? It does not work appropriately :(

```
(define (vacations destinations prices budget)
  (cond
    [(empty? destinations) empty]
    [(<= budget (first prices)) (cons (string-append (first destinations) " " (int->string (first prices)))
                                     (vacations (rest destinations) (rest prices) budget))]
    [else (vacations (rest destinations) (rest prices) budget)]))

(check-expect (vacations (list "Maldives") (list 1599) 250) empty)
(check-expect (vacations(list "Maldives") (list 1599) 1599)
              (list "Maldives 1599"))
(check-expect (vacations(list "Alberta" "BC" "Manitoba") (list 500 459 300) 460)
              (list "BC 459" "Manitoba 300"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is almost correct. Then only error is the comparison operator in the second branch of the conditional:

`(<= budget (first prices))` means if the budget is less or equal to the price, then consider the place as possibile vacation.

Simply reverse the condition:

`(>= budget (first prices))`: if the budget is greater than or equal to the price,  then consider the place as possibile vacation.